# How can I do TDD and Unit Testing for EF Code First entity declaration and mapping?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, tdd, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have am about to retro-code a suite of unit tests for a new MVC4 app. Because nearly all my code in the EF data project is copied straight from code generated by the VS2012 EF Reverse Engineering tool, I have decided to skip unit tests in this part of the application, unless I can somehow automatically generate them. I have no business logic at here and I would like to first concentrate my efforts on ensuring better QA on the business side. But, I would like to know how one goes about first TDD, and second, just unit testing in general here.

Let's assume I don't have to or want to mock the database yet. I have often been quite happy unit testing against a test DB copy before, but with more conventional, home rolled ORM.

So, do I start with a test that instantiates my drived DbContext, then derive a DbContext until that test passes. Then, test for instantiating an entity, and create an entity, going on to test for a DbSet of those entities, which test will also include checking if the table is created. All is still good and well, if not bloody laborious, but my head asplode as soon as I start thinking of even a hint of testing my fluent mapping classes for all my entities. What now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing against database is not unit testing - it is integration testing and integration testing usually doesn't follow the granularity of unit testing. Why it is not unit testing? Because unit testing tests single self contained unit - all external dependencies are faked. When your test spans both your unit code and database it test dependency as well = it is integration test.

All EF dependent code should be tested with integration testing. It doesn't make sense to unit test Microsoft's code. For example your question about mapping. Correct unit test for mapping does something like:

- Preparation: Prepare compiled model with your entity mapping configuration
- Execution: Create DbContext from compiled model and get metadata workspace from the context
- Validation: Assert that metadata context contains your mapped entity

Now you can repeat similar test for every property you want to map in that entity.

That is obviously framework code which should already work - these tests should be done by people developing the framework.

In your case simple make integration test against local database which will try to load, save, update and delete entity and assert expectations you have on these operations. If anything in mapping is wrong at least one of these tests will fail.

Comment: I mean testing against code I write to guarantee FK's etc. on the DB, not against the DB or DB library itself.  E.g. write a test for an `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` class.

Comment: "That is obviously framework code which should already work"... Just because an entity definition can be instantiated and applied to a model doesn't mean its *actual* metadata meets your expectations. The latter is *not* something the EF Team can possibly know about. Therefore, properly testing your own configuration classes isn't any less pertinent than testing for proper string value in a simple input / output api. Would you advocate that it's pointless because you're not the String class author? :)