# How am I supposed to unit test EntityTypeConfiguration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

I know this has been asked before, and invariably someone comes along and says "That's not a unit test, that's an integration test." I'm just going call bullshit on that.

So Lets consider a really simple entity and its map:

```
public class Tag
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}

public class TagConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tag>
{
    public TagConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Tag", "dbo")
            .HasKey(tag => tag.Id);

        Property(tag => tag.Id)
            .HasColumnType(SqlDbType.BigInt.ToString())
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(tag => tag.Text)
           .HasColumnType(SqlDbType.NVarChar.ToString())
           .HasMaxLength(64)
           .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Basically we are looking at an entity that is a number keyed to a string.

What is it I want to test here? Well I don't really see why I shouldn't be able to Create an instance of TagConfiguration and make a few assertions about the object.

- Is the Table name correct?
- Is the Schema name correct?
- Are the long fields mapped to a SQL BigInt and not an SQL Int?
- Are the long fields going to a NOT NULL column?
- Is the Text field mapped to a NVarChar and not VarCar?
- Is the Text field going to a NOT NULL column?
- Is the Max Length of the Text long enough.

Think about it this way, this class is a parameter to some Entity Framework code. I don't need to test what Entity Framework does with it, because that's Entity Framework's Business, but I do need to test that I am correctly generating the parameter.

If this was code that calculated the users account balance, and that balance was used by EF code to update the database, I wouldn't test the update code, but I sure would test the code that calculated the balance that will be passed to the update code.

[This guy asked basically the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283417/how-can-i-do-tdd-and-unit-testing-for-ef-code-first-entity-declaration-and-mappi#) and if you look at his comment on the accepted answer you'll see that he didn't get what he was looking for.

What I'm looking for here is one of the following:

- Here is how you test this:
- A *really* good reason with an intelligible explanation why I don't need to.

Comment: Well isn't an integration test just a unite test that actually dose something useful. Simple answer don't use EntityTypeConfiguration why do you think it's not in EF7. Here is something that is more testable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-7-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration.

Comment: @FilipCordas, Do you mean Entity Framework Core?

Comment: @WiliamLeader Yes I mean core, but the same way of configuring can be use in EF6.  The Configure method has EntityTypeBuilder<T> as input so you can just mock that. The EntityTypeConfiguration was never a good idea.

Comment: What versiojn of visual studio do you use? With Enterprise you can easily do this with Microsoft fakes.

Comment: @zaitsman I think any Mocking framework can do inheritance mocking the problem I had with that is the work in the constructor. Might be just me but I think it's unnecessarily difficult and lacks control.

Comment: @FilipCordas FYI in EF Core you can create `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementations. These allows not only for better SoC but also for multiple configurations based on different database configurations, which can then be set without requiring a whole new DbContext instance to pass around.

Comment: @WilliamLeader I have yet to figure out how to test mapping logic inside configuration classes. The biggest problem really is that you cannot create an instance of EntityTypeBuilder, which IMHO is just silly.

Comment: @Crono I do know that I think I posted this before it was added to EF Core. And IEntityTypeConfiguration  is much better then EntityTypeConfiguration. It has a configure method that receives EntityTypeBuilder object. You can mock that in a simpler manner and see what methods are called and with what. The way I recommended for him to do.